# Phaser with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I'm trying to capture a click event and change a game state but I constantly get "undefined" error. I use this code to add game states:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'canvas');
game.state.add('Boot', Boot);
game.state.add('Level_1', Level_1);
game.state.start('Boot');
```

Here I run game intro and try to capture a click event

```
var button;
var Boot = function(game) {};

Boot.prototype = {
preload: function() {
    this.load.image('logo','img/logo_allcomp_white.png');
    this.load.image('welcome','img/welcome.png');
    this.load.image('gradient','img/gradient.png');
},

create: function() {
    this.add.sprite(0,0,'gradient');
    this.stage.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
    this.add.sprite(20,20,'logo');
    var cutters = this.add.tileSprite(0, 0, this.game.width, this.game.height,'welcome');
    cutters.autoScroll(-20,0);
    button = document.getElementById('startbtn');
    button.addEventListener('click',this.updateButton);
},

updateButton: function() {
this.game.state.start('Level_1');
}
};
```

I cannot get it to work. Is this even possible to interact with other DOM elements outside the canvas? Adding this button to canvas doesn't work for me. I must keep my control panel outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your updateButton you reference the game as `this.game`, while in the scope of the function `this` refers to the button being pressed, making `this.game` undefined. You can just call your game with `game.state.start('Level_1');`

I've created a pen for you: http://codepen.io/kozulowski/pen/YPvyzW

Comment: @przemoo83 You might wanna look into `Function.prototype.bind`: `button.addEventListener('click',this.updateButton.bind(this))`